# Neo4jClient: decimal point dropped

Tags: decimal, neo4jclient

I'm having trouble using properties of type `decimal` in my program, which uses Neo4jClient to interact with my Neo4J server.

```cs
using System;
using Neo4jClient;

namespace TestProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
            graphClient.Connect();

            const decimal socialFactor = 0.5m;

            var userIn = new User {Name = "John Doe", SocialFactor = socialFactor};
            var nodeRef = graphClient.Create(userIn);
            var userOut = graphClient.Get(nodeRef).Data;

            Console.WriteLine(userOut.Name + ", " + userOut.SocialFactor);
            Console.WriteLine(userOut.SocialFactor == socialFactor ? "win" : "fail!");
        }
    }

    class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal SocialFactor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What the program does is insert a user node with a social factor of 0.5 into Neo4j (`userIn`), and immediately retrieves the user node again (`userOut`). The problem is that `userOut.SocialFactor` is 5 instead of 0.5!

Strangely enough, when I change the type to `double`, there is no problem, but that's obviously something I don't want to do.

Is this a bug? Is there some kind of workaround?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: What version of Neo4jclient are you using? I'm using 1.0.0.594 and copying your code and running it in a console app (nice work on supplying a fully working program btw!) I get 0.5 and 'Win' back.

Comment: @ChrisSkardon: yes, that's exactly the version I'm using and I get 5 and fail back. I found out it has to do something with the culture of my system. We use the comma as the decimal "point" over here. When I change my settings to use an actual dot, the program works as expected. Do you think it's a bug?

Comment: I would add it to the neo4jclient issues page (https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issues?status=new&status=open) with the whole code, but I have to say - I'm unable to get that to happen, if I add the line `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");` above my code (France uses ',' ) I still get the result back fine, so.. What culture are you using, where are you changing the culture?

Comment: @ChrisSkardon: I change it in the Windows Control Panel under Region and Language. Pick "Dutch (Belgium)" for example. If I understand Neo4jClient's source code correctly, the current thread is not necessarily the thread that parses the JSON response so that might explain things.

Comment: Bingo! got it replicating... OK, there is a class in Neo4jclient `CustomJsonDeserializer` that takes a `CultureInfo` item and when I've *hardcoded* to 'fr-FR' returns me the correct answer, HOWEVER, I can't figure out how to inject that into the client in any way - I presume there is a way, as that's what the overload does, but I can't see how, as it is 'newed' up, not used injection wise..

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the constructor taking the `CultureInfo` is only used in the unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that yes, it was a bug but it was recently fixed in [version 1.0.0.595](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4jClient/1.0.0.595) of Neo4jClient.